# ¿Cómo aplicar onchange y dentro un código PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Tengo un `select` que se llena según una tabla en mi base de datos *MySQL*, pero quiero que cuando elijo un valor me haga una consulta a mi base de datos y me busque, por ejemplo, un valor en otra tabla y que lo muestre. Por ejemplo, en `label` abajo, pero sin usar un botón, solo cambiando el valor de mi `select`.

¿Alguna idea de cómo podría hacerlo?

Código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $document(".comorbilidad").change(function(){
    var localizacion = document.getElementById("localizacion").value;
    <?php 
      $cosulta_tabla = "SELECT name from tratamiento where cod_tip_tratamiento='1' and cod_loc_enf='localizacion'"
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$cosulta_tabla)

      while($row = $resultado->fetch_Array()){
        $valor=$row['name']
      }
    ?>
    document.getElementById("name_uy").innerHTML =<?php echo $valor>;
  })
</script>
```

Sé que está mal pero esa es la idea que tenía de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Tendrás que usar ajax para poder hacerlo, donde en tu php tengas la consulta, regreses `$valor` y desde ahí puedas asignarlo a tu elemento `name_uy`

Comment: Puedes usar Ajax (n refrescarias la página) o haciendo el *submit* en el **onchange** (refrescarias la página); desde luego pasando el valor. Recuerda que el código PHP se ejecuta en el servidor y nada **<?php [lo que pongas] ?>** en el navegador del cliente

Answer (score 1):

Pues como está taggeado Jquery te recomiendo lo siguiente

```
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.comorbilidad', function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'dame_tag.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          value: value
        },
        success: function(respuesta) {
          $('#name_uy').html(respuesta);
        }
      });
    });
  }); 
  </script>
```

En el dame_tag.php lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
$cosulta_tabla = "SELECT name from tratamiento where cod_tip_tratamiento='1' and cod_loc_enf='".$_REQUEST["value"]."'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$cosulta_tabla);
$row = $resultado->fetch_Array()
echo $row['name'];
 ?>
```

O como dice inye, agregar un atributo al las option cuando armes el código.

Que te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que yo creo que podrías hacer si no es muy largo el texto que quieres colocar en `label`, es que cuando generes el `select` a cada opción le agregues un `data-` (data-textlabel podría ser), quedando algo asi:

```
...
<option value="4" data-textlabel="Texto opcion 4 que se mostrará en label">Opción 4</option>
<option value="5" data-textlabel="Texto opcion 5 que se mostrará en label">Opción 5</option>
...
```

Con eso podrías obtener en `onchange` el `data-textlabel` y desplegarlo en el `label`.

Tu jquery sería algo como esto:

```
$('select. comorbilidad').change(function() { 
var text = $('select. comorbilidad').find(':selected').data('textlabel'); 
$('#name_uy').val(text); });
```